# Running Clang-Tidy on a Large Project

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compilation, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

I ran `clang-tidy` (Clang-Extra-Tools 6.0.0) in the root directory of the source code of an application (`MPlayer-1.3.0`). Precisely, I use `run-clang-tidy.py` python script, as follows:

```
run-clang-tidy.py -header-filter='.*' -checks='-*,readability-braces-around-statements' -fix
```

The commands database is also stored in the root directory in a file named `compile_commands.json`. After gathering all fixes, it tries to apply them but no fix is applied on any of the source files compiled from the **inner** directories. Here is the first part of the error report:

```
Applying fixes ...
Described file './libavutil/internal.h' doesn't exist. 
Ignoring...
Described file './libavutil/x86/intmath.h' doesn't exist. 
Ignoring...
Described file 'libavformat/internal.h' doesn't exist. 
Ignoring...
Described file './libavcodec/bytestream.h' doesn't exist. 
Ignoring...
Described file './libavcodec/flac.h' doesn't exist. 
Ignoring...
Described file './libavcodec/get_bits.h' doesn't exist. 
Ignoring...
Described file './libavcodec/internal.h' doesn't exist. 
Ignoring...
Described file './libavcodec/mathops.h' doesn't exist. 
Ignoring...
Described file './libavcodec/put_bits.h' doesn't exist. 
Ignoring...
Described file 'libavformat/matroskaenc.c' doesn't exist. 
Ignoring...
Described file 'libavformat/subtitles.h' doesn't exist. 
Ignoring...
Described file 'libavformat/apngdec.c' doesn't exist. 
Ignoring...
...
```

These files are compiled using the Makefile located in the folder `ffmpeg`. For example, `libavformat/apngdec.c` is located at `./ffmpeg/libavformat/apngdec.c` where `.` is the root directory of `MPlayer-1.3.0`. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, it was a bug in `Clang Tidy`. It only happens in the case of exports. This happens in cases such as when the `run-clang-tidy` script is called with `-fix` switch. The main problem is that the fixes stored in the export file should use absolute paths. This usually happens with projects using `CMAKE` to generate the compile commands database. But `MPlayer` uses `Makefile` as the build system and I used `Bear` to generate the database. There are also problems with merging the fixes to the same location.

To fix the problem, mainly, I constructed absolute paths and made some other changes similar to those for the code without export. Finally, the `YAML` export file is revised and generated. The patch is [here](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20180723/236426.html).